# IO object for only part of a file

Tags: ruby, object, io

I have files encapsulated in a bigger file (similar to a [TAR file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tar_(computing)#File_format)) that I would like to be able to easily access it using the [`IO` methods](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/IO.html).

For example if I have a 3 KiB file, I would like to have an object representing only the middle 1 KiB, so I can the following:

```
middle.size      #=> 1024
middle.rewind
middle.pos       #=> 0
middle.read.size #=> 1024
middle.pos       #=> 1024
```

- Should I expand the `IO` class in some way?
- Should I create a new class inheriting from `IO`?
- Can I fake just the middle to be a file before instantiating `IO`?

Answer (score 1):

Your third option, "faking just the middle", is what's called a proxy or wrapper, and that's usually the simplest way to do this. You emulate IO methods, but you actually adjust everything according to your offset values.

For example:

```
class OffsetIO
  def initialize(name, options = nil)
    options ||= { }
    @offset = (options[:offset] || 0).to_i
    @file = File.open(name, options)
  end

  # Example method that applies an offset
  def rewind
    @file.seek(@offset)
  end

  def seek(offset)
    @file.seek(offset + @offset)
  end

  def method_missing(*args)
    @file.send(*args)
  end
end
```

You could also subclass File, but I'm not sure if redefining things like `seek` would mess with its internals.

Comment: *Wrapper* was the word I was looking for. It's what I had until now, I was wondering if there was anything more serious. What is the `method_missing` method? Does it catch "everything else"?

Comment: Yeah, it's a catch-all so you don't have to re-write every single method.